# Jenkins email extension plugin can not find the file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-email-ext

I config jenkins email extension plugin, i want add a picture to the email content, below is my code, but i get an error in the email that the path does not exist.PLZ help.

```
BUILD_FILE :${FILE,path="automation\\1.jpg"}
```